# how to open JQuery model popup dialog over iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, iframe

I am using `JQuery UI dialog` for modal popups. I have some `iframes` in my page as well. I open the modal dialog from iframe but it will open within iframe.

I want when model popup is open then user cant allow to click on background link.

So please let me know how can i `prevent user to click on background area`?

Answer (score 1):

The iframe is a page within a page. if you use dialog in the page loaded in the iframe it will load in the iframe. What you need to do is to add the code to open the dialog box on the main page or use parent to call the parent page and execute the javascript code. There is a problem if the iframe and the parent page share the same domain you have access to the parent javascript if they are different domains your iframe can not access the parent javascript. A work around is to use postMessage. You will need to add the code to open the dialog box in the main page and use postMessage to communicate between the parent and the iframe this are security restrictions of all browsers.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

By Setting `model : true` you can prevent the background area click from user in `JQuery`.

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#popupId" ).dialog({
       modal: true
    });
 });
```

Refer Basic Model Popup from [JqueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal)

Answer (score 0):

[DEmo Here Its Solution](http://jsbin.com/uruyob/1/edit)

One of the things that has worked for me is to have an iframe inside the div that is your dialog, and set its url property on the open event.

Like:

Open Dialog
And JS:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 600,
    open: function(ev, ui){
             $('#myIframe').attr('src','http://www.jQuery.com');
          }
});

$('#dialogBtn').click(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog('open');
});
```

You would find that you need some styling on the iframe to get it look nice, though.

```
#myIframe{
  height: 580px;
}
```